# of no interest or not of interest?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions

An official document from my University (HAN Arnhem, the Netherlands) is full of typos, for instance,

*...to interrupt a task when a peripheral signals **an** hardware event.*

et cetera, et cetera. But what really aggravates me is,

*...a mask is used to ignore all bits not of interest.*

I'd rather write *of no interest*. **Am I mistaken?**

Comment: Does *bits* here refer to *binary digits*?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Indeed, digital electronics. I've just learned how to use different colours to find the minterms in a Karnuagh map. But this document is really annoying is full of typos and the grammatic is a real bummer.

Comment: I mean the sentence order is sometimes a real bummer, really weird.

Comment: Both forms are grammatical.

Comment: @Lawrence Are you sure? I mean sorry but I cannot simply believe in something that you just say. I upvoted your comment. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, “not of interest” is such a common expression that it even features in [acronyms](http://m.acronymsandslang.com/definition/817258/MNOI-meaning.html).

Comment: Here is some example usage of [not of interest](https://ludwig.guru/s/is+not+of+interest).

Comment: You could tidy up the wording with “ignoring selected bits” or “ignoring irrelevant bits”.

Comment: @Lawrence That's the ordeal of reading a document with so many typos that everything, that's being ran into, looks suspiciously wrong and therefore makes the whole experience a real bummer, hideous. Thanks for the advice (appreciated) and for your time! (I shall accept an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "not of interest" is idiomatic, so much so that it is included in acronyms:

- [NOI](https://www.acronymattic.com/Not-of-Interest-(NOI).html): Not of Interest
- [MNOI](http://m.acronymsandslang.com/definition/817258/MNOI-meaning.html): Messages Not of Interest
- [SNOI](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Signal_Not_Of_Interest-(SNOI).html): Signal Not of Interest

Here are a couple of instances of its use in official documents:

- "The membership of S.A. in various international bodies should be reviewed in order to lessen Australia’s role in matters not of interest to Australia and to remove the exclusive roles of S.A. in international matters."
  -[Productivity Commission (Australia)](https://www.pc.gov.au/inquiries/completed/standards/submissions/dr_richard_aynsley,_nswusa_revised/sub039.rtf) (links to a document)
- "We realize of course that Diem’s general mode of operation leaves little opportunity for his interlocutors to bring up matters not of interest to him"
- [Office of the Historian (USA)](https://history.state.gov/historicaldocuments/frus1961-63v04/d218)

"Not of interest" is typically used in a formal register. It would be considered unremarkable in the context of a technical manual's commentary on bit masks. Replacing "not of interest" with "of no interest" shifts the tone slightly from neutral to one that is somewhat disparaging.